# I need some help on Usenet

Tags: macos

I need help with Usenet. Does anyone know how to navigate around it easily? if so have any pointers for me? or any advice on how to use this?

Looking for a useable build 14A389. for my computer!
OSX 10.10.2 for mac.

Comment: Why don't you just get it from the App Store or Internet Recovery?

Comment: 14A389 is 10.10 (10.10.0), not 10.10.2. 10.10.2 would be 14C109 (or 14C1514 if you have Security Update 2015-003).

Answer (score 1):

You can use

Google Groups

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!overview

type the name of a group e.g. alt.computer hit enter, click alt.computer

[image]

Then click it and you see you have a forum like interface to that newsgroup of usenet.  Or any other newsgroup if you enter it in the search bar and click it.

[image]

If you want a News Client, a bit like how outlook express does email, a program that accesses usenet i'm sure Mac/OSX users have some suggestions.

Comment: "XanaNews is a free, powerful, fully featured newsreader for Windows 98, Windows 2000 and Windows XP." OP is using "OSX 10.10.2"

Comment: @DavidPostill good point I just removed about xana news.

Comment: You'd also need an alt.binaries group, which Google won't search

Comment: Actually using Usenet, I found that file in about 5 seconds flat, but I'm not sure why anyone would need to access it that way unless it was for a hackintosh, so I'm not going to post the link

Comment: @Tetsujin what interface/program do you use for usenet?

Comment: I use a paid service usually, with an entire html/web interface & search engine - easynews.com - for regular NNTP access I always used to use MT-NewsWatcher, which no longer works. These days, I'd have to go back to Google to find a new one - http://www.usenet-mac.com [untested] might be useful

Comment: Actually that link I left looks like a typical, *"Which is the best… oh, that'll be ours… & no it's not actually free"* site - please choose to ignore